# how to pull a null check for `item.GetType().GetProperty(getPropertyStringParameter)` in linq

Tags: c#, linq

how to put a check for null like,

`if(item.GetType().GetProperty(getPropertyStringParameter) != null)` for below linq query in C#?

```
 matchingConfigItem = (from item in contextEnum
                            where item.GetType().GetProperty(getPropertyStringParameter).GetValue(item)
                                .Equals(configItem.GetType().GetProperty(getPropertyStringParameter)
                                    ?.GetValue(configItem))
                            select item).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Have a look at the null conditional operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matchingConfigItem = (
   from item in contextEnum
   let itemProp = item.GetType().GetProperty(getPropertyStringParameter)
   let configProp = configItem.GetType().GetProperty(getPropertyStringParameter)
   where itemProp != null && configProp != null && itemProp.GetValue(item)
   .Equals(configProp.GetValue(configItem))
   select item
)
.SingleOrDefault();
```